# Changing the theme of Google Map on click - React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have react native maps and I am setting the custom map theme as `this.state.mapTheme`.

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        mapTheme: Themes.SANANDREAS
    }
}
```

And I have the render method as such:

```
render() {
    return (
        <Container style ={styles.container}>      
            <Button rounded style={styles.contributeButton} onPress={() => {
                this.setState({
                    mapTheme: Themes.BROWNTHEME
                })
            }} iconLeft light>
              <Icon name='hand' />
              <Text>Contribute</Text>
            </Button>
            <MapView
                style={styles.map}
                provider = { MapView.PROVIDER_GOOGLE }
                customMapStyle = { this.state.mapTheme }
            ></MapView>
        </Container>
);}
```

It all seems to be working, but when I change the state on press of the button, the render method is getting called but the theme does
not change. Both of my themes are working but on press nothing happens. The page reloads but without the new theme being used. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering the [MapView](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/lib/components/MapView.js) component's lifecycle functions it won't update the styles automatically if new style props is passed. You should force it by calling `_updateStyle` after theme change directly with the help of 'ref':

```
setMapRef = ref => this.mapRef = ref;

handleButtonClick = () => {
  this.setState({ mapTheme: Themes.BROWNTHEME }, () => {
    this.mapRef._updateStyle();
  })
}

render() {
  return (
     <Container>      
       <Button onPress={this.handleButtonClick}
         title="Update map theme"
       />
       <MapView
         ref={this.setMapRef}
         customMapStyle={this.state.mapTheme}
       />
     </Container>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yeah it worked, is there any way the transition can be animated?

Comment: I suggest to google to `setNativeProps` + `animation` as `_updateStyle` is using `setNativeProps`. But this does not seems to be an easy topic to animate all the map colors separately.

Comment: Hey, I was trying to implement the same theme change in reactjs now using google-maps-react. Is there any equivalent to the `_updateStyle()` function?

Comment: I had a quick view on the implementation, I am guessing that `restyleMap` method might be equivalent: https://github.com/fullstackreact/google-maps-react/blob/0f985dc1da051efa38acd23fc1230f2d7014035c/src/index.js#L222